# Organic chemistry( basics)

Tags: organic-chemistry

[image: Q-Which of the following compound has negligible enol?]

I have a confusion here .Why option (a) have minimum enol content.According to me enol content is related to stability ,so only compound a is undergoing resonance so it must have a maximum resonating structure ,but the reverse happens here.Please explain me if stability is not the factor which determine enol content or I am wrong??

Comment: Keto-enol enol is considered after sufficient time has passed for the equilibrium to be attained, and thus is a form of thermodynamic control regulated by Gibbs free energy

Comment: In this question, enol of (d) will be stabilized by a 6 member hydrogen bonded ring. (C) is forced to undergo tautomerism to minimize dipolar repulsion between the oxygens. (B) on tautomerizing forms an aromatic compound while (a) forms an anti aromatic one. So (A) is least stable

Comment: @YUSUFHASAN option d contains only 5 carbon. So how it form 6member ring.If c have repulsion than option b have more repulsion than c.And,how a form anti aeromatic ring can you explain this question to me with the help of diagram please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last option is forming a six members ring via intramolecular H-bonding, and the said ring consists of 3 carbons, 2 oxygens and 1 hydrogen. For option B, you are right, dipolar repulsions will be present, and on top of that, the 2π electrons(denoted by e-s in my diagram) will ensure that the tautomerism takes place. Although dipolar repulsions still exist after this step, but since we are out of acidic hydrogens, so this is the best configuration the molecule can acquire. Finally, option A will form an enolate possessing 4π electrons, and by Huckel's rule, it is antiaromatic in nature
[Diagrammatic representation](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ZQaTpKsntBPJ64aNe67ZgUCTGSgTWfkJ/view?usp=drivesdk)